# C pointers and malloc confusion between &str,str

Tags: malloc

Im a beginner in C,In the following code what can be the output value of &str and str when it is cast as an integer.??

```
int main()
{
   char *str;

   /* Initial memory allocation */

   str = (char *) malloc(15);

   strcpy(str, "Hello");

   printf("String = %s,  Address = %d ,val=%d\n", str, &str,str);


   free(str);

   return(0);
}
```

This is the output i got:

String = Hello,  Address = -1407247144 ,val=22335504

Comment: Please read up on the `&` operator - Google it! Should tell you the answer

Comment: yea..i did..the & operator is supposed to give the address ryt?whereas here str gives the address and &str giving some junk value..really doubt my understanding btw.

Comment: `&str` - is not a junk value. It is the address where of the variable `str`. This variable happens to store an address - the one returned from `malloc`. BTW You do not need the cast